# sort multiple variables in ascending order

Tags: php

I have a table that sorts ascending using a $playerTotals variable. It works, but now I want it to also sort by another variable named $closestID. I have tried a few things, but get nothing but errors.

```
$i = 0;
arsort($playerTotals);
foreach($playerTotals as $userID => $totalCorrect) {
    $hidePicks = hidePicks($userID, $week);
    if ($i == 0) {
        $topScore = $totalCorrect;
        $winners[] = $userID;
    } else if ($totalCorrect == $topScore) {
        $winners[] = $userID;
    }
```

I have tried:

```
$i = 0;
arsort($playerTotals, $closestID);
```

That does not work though.

Really, All I want is for $closestID to show at the top of the list, and then sort by $playerTotals... is that possible?

Comment: I don't think it will work for what I am doing. Honestly, I don't really know how to use it.

Comment: try with [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) manipulate with second parameter

Comment: I tried that with this: `array_multisort($playerTotals, SORT_ASC, $closestID, SORT_ASC);` but it doesn't work. I also get an error: array_multisort() [function.array-multisort]: Argument #3 is expected to be an array or a sort flag

Comment: remove second parameter `SORT_ASC` . see this too => http://goo.gl/ctnNlk